# Multiple Returns to one Ajax Call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my page, users can search a rather big database for entries that contain a search expression. The search is ajaxified and integrates smoothly, however it takes some seconds for it to complete. So I was wondering whether or not it is possible to have the controller send multiple returns to one single ajax call?

If so, I would rather reprogramm the search so that it takes a bit longer but displays each match as soon as it identifies it.

Comment: Can't you use pagination?

Comment: I could but I'd rather have the results fly in one by one..

Comment: One request will always have one response. If you want to break your results into multiple smaller responses you'll need you make multiple requests.

Comment: Hm so 100 individual results = 100 individual ajax requests..

Comment: Right. So, hopefully you see the flaw in your design at this point. Maybe you should have each request ask for 10 - 15 results instead.

Comment: may be divide the results into set of 10 that way only 10 request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to improve performace on my query, and then implement something like infinite scroll (http://www.infinite-scroll.com/)

Answer (score 0):

i agree with Yuck. one request will always have one request but you can animate them to show one by one when dislaying..